# Grouping of data into different tables based on minimum date of an event

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in the below format:

```
+---------+------------+--------+
| Cust_id |    Date    | fruits |
+---------+------------+--------+
|   10001 | 12/01/2019 | Apple  |
|   10001 | 02/02/2019 | Orange |
|   10001 | 05/02/2019 | Apple  |
|   10001 | 08/09/2018 | Banana |
|   10001 | 30/10/2019 | Apple  |
|   10001 | 01/11/2019 | Orange |
|   10001 | 01/01/2020 | Banana |
|   10002 | 21/01/2019 | Apple  |
|   10002 | 03/02/2019 | Orange |
|   10002 | 06/02/2019 | Apple  |
|   10002 | 07/09/2018 | Banana |
|   10002 | 3/10/2019  | Apple  |
|   10002 | 30/11/2019 | Orange |
|   10002 | 05/01/2020 | Banana |
|   10003 | 21/01/2019 | Banana |
|   10003 | 03/02/2019 | Orange |
|   10003 | 06/02/2019 | Apple  |
|   10003 | 07/09/2018 | Banana |
|   10003 | 03/10/2019 | Apple  |
|   10003 | 30/11/2019 | Orange |
|   10003 | 05/01/2020 | Banana |
+---------+------------+--------+
```

I need to create 3 tables based on the below conditions (Hence the sample result):

Table Apple:

```
+--------+------------+-------+
| Custid |    Date    | fruit |
+--------+------------+-------+
|  10001 | 12/01/2019 | Apple |
+--------+------------+-------+
```

This table will have all customers who have become apple in the given period of time atleast once. Consider Min date when they became apple.

Table Orange:

```
+--------+------------+--------+
| Custid |    Date    | fruit  |
+--------+------------+--------+
|  10002 | 03/02/2019 | Orange |
+--------+------------+--------+
```

This table contains all customers who are not in Table apple and have become Orange atleast once in the given period of time. Consider min date when they became Orange.

Table Banana:

```
+--------+------------+--------+
| Custid |    Date    | fruit  |
+--------+------------+--------+
|  10003 | 07/09/2018 | Banana |
+--------+------------+--------+
```

This table contains all customers who are not in table apple and orange.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff can u help me out here...

Comment: All customers purchased apples, so the sample result is not consistent with your sample data

Comment: Sample data may have.. but real data may or may not have every fruit. Whenever there is a change an new row is inserted with increase in version.The first table to create is apple. So I shd check all customers who were apple atleast once.and use min( date) in target table

Answer (score 2):

Using a MIN as analytic function you can calulate the fruit that should be considered for a customer.

As the order is not alphabetic you must help with a `DECODE`

Rest is a simple group by with a `MIN` for the purhase date, but considering only the purchases with the MIN fruit.

```
with cust as (
select CUST_ID, PURCH_DATE, FRUIT,
decode(min(decode(FRUIT,'Apple',1,'Orange',2,'Banana',3)) over (partition by cust_id),
       1,'Apple',2,'Orange',3,'Banana') as min_fruit       
from tab)
select CUST_ID,min_fruit,
       min(case when FRUIT = MIN_FRUIT then PURCH_DATE end) min_purch_date
from cust
group by CUST_ID,min_fruit
order by 1,2
```

Bellow is an alternative solution *without using analytic functions*.

The first subquery calculate the *minimal fruit* with a silpme `group by` using the same `DECODE` logik.

You must join the subquery to the original table which is exact what you can save using analytical functions.

```
with min_fruit as (
select CUST_ID, 
decode(min(decode(FRUIT,'Apple',1,'Orange',2,'Banana',3)),
       1,'Apple',2,'Orange',3,'Banana') as min_fruit       
from tab
group by cust_id)
select cust.CUST_ID,min_fruit fruit,
       min(case when FRUIT = MIN_FRUIT then PURCH_DATE end) min_purch_date
from tab cust
join min_fruit on cust.cust_id = min_fruit.cust_id
group by cust.CUST_ID,min_fruit
order by 1,2;
```

With you sample data this returns

```
   CUST_ID FRUIT  MIN_PURCH_DATE     
---------- ------ -------------------
     10001 Apple  12.01.2019 00:00:00
     10002 Apple  21.01.2019 00:00:00
     10003 Apple  06.02.2019 00:00:00
```

Comment: Can u help me with the above concept by using only SQL query. I m very much new here in Oracle sql

Comment: @akr this *is* SQL. If you mean a solution without analytic function* I added one.

Comment: Hi @Marmite I want to consider 10001 only for apple. As first 10001 has become apple with min date. Once i consider 10001 for table apple, i will not consider that customer for any other fruit

Comment: sorry i got confused with with min_fruit as ( so said i need just normal sql query

Answer (score 2):

I would not split this into three tables.  Instead, I would create one table with one row per `cust_id` and `fruit`.  The second column would specify what you mean by "separate tables".

You can do this with aggregation and a some conditional logic:

```
select cust_id,
       coalesce( max(case when fruits = 'Apple' then fruits end),
                 max(case when fruits = 'Orange' then fruits end),
                 max(case when fruits = 'Banana' then fruits end)
               ) as fruit,
       coalesce( min(case when fruits = 'Apple' then date end),
                 min(case when fruits = 'Orange' then date end),
                 min(case when fruits = 'Banana' then date end)
               ) as date
from t
where fruits in ('Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana')  -- not needed if these are the only three values
group by cust_id;
```

You can filter this rather than creating separate tables -- or use a `having` clause if you really need to filter for a particular group.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ed0c573668256b6b3cb6f0fa6dbdcda6) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: 2 conditions- Once considered for apple, do not consider for other, get the minimum date wen they were apple. Is this both satisfied?

Comment: @akr . . . I added a db<>fiddle.  All your customers have Apples, so the results are not what is in your question.

Comment: The real data may or may not have apple, if atleast once they were apple we will be considering in apple bucket.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the below query.

CREATE TABLE apple AS
SELECT DISTINCT
FIRST_VALUE(cust_id) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY MIN_PURCH_DATE ASC) AS cust_id
,FIRST_VALUE(MIN_PURCH_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY MIN_PURCH_DATE ASC) AS MIN_PURCH_DATE
from (select * from ALL_DATA where fruit='apple')

CREATE TABLE orange AS
SELECT DISTINCT
FIRST_VALUE(cust_id) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY MIN_PURCH_DATE ASC) AS cust_id
,FIRST_VALUE(MIN_PURCH_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY MIN_PURCH_DATE ASC) AS MIN_PURCH_DATE
from (select * from ALL_DATA where fruit='orange' where custid not in ( select distinct custid from apple))

CREATE TABLE banana AS
SELECT DISTINCT
FIRST_VALUE(cust_id) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY MIN_PURCH_DATE ASC) AS cust_id
,FIRST_VALUE(MIN_PURCH_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY MIN_PURCH_DATE ASC) AS MIN_PURCH_DATE
from (select * from ALL_DATA where fruit='orange' where custid not in ( select distinct custid from apple union sleect distinct custid from orange))