# Differentiating records based on the occurence

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is the Sample Data

[source table here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w61ZM.png)

with the above data i need to create 3 tables having data as below;

[Target tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObtgH.png)

Even once the customer turns red, he should be in Red bucket with minimum data he went on Red.
Orange = Target table-Red and have orange atleast once with minimum date
Green= Target table-Red-Orange(Obviously he would be green)

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63665478/4808122) the same question - only in different option? You should show some effort - SO is not a quiz solving service.

Comment: Let me refer to the solutions in that link. Thank you. I have drafted few queries will post it too.